# Preparing for a long distance ride - long term

Tags: road-bike, training, long-distance, preparation

I've done long rides in the past, the longest of which was 259 km less than 2 years ago, but I've fallen very much out of shape.

I am currently overweight, but I know how to solve this part and by the time I want to do the ride in question, I should weigh around 85 kg. I'm 184 cm tall as a frame of reference.

I would like to do a 280 km ride in May next year, with elevation gain probably exceeding 3000 m - hard to find flat routes where I live. Currently, most rides I do are around 25 km long - I think I could manage a 60 km ride now, but it wouldn't be fun in my current shape. What are the steps I can take, apart from losing weight and just cycling, to ensure I'm ready to do this come next May?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have more than enough time, so use it.

Start at 25km, increase distance by 10% per week.  This would mean just six months to 280km. Key thing is start slowly, don't over do it, because of your time frame, do less not more, if you take time off (more than a couple of weeks), drop back a bit. Plot a line on a calendar - from now at 25km to May next year at 280km, this is the easiest to sustained buildup. Plot another line, From November at 25km to May. Think to yourself this is the line you must no drop under. For most people, due to 'life' getting in the way of training the reality will be in between these lines.

Better to do 3 rides a week than one big one. Every few weeks have an easy week where you do maybe 1/2 to 2/3 of you previous week.

The biggest obstacles will be being short of time during the week, in which case maximise you training effort, but make sure you get at least one long ride a month in. Failing to get out over winter (depending where you live) can be a problem, indoor trainer, or cross training at gym and pool will get you though winter in good shape. Still try to get out on the bike if you can.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I especially like the idea of the two plots, feel like that could really be motivating for me. Winter is not much of an issue here in Sydney, apart from short days interfering with my rides on work days. I'll wait to see if anyone else has anything to add and then accept.

Comment: OK, Sydney huh, swap winter for summer. Biking if 45C is not fun :) .....

Comment: I guess I'll just ride at night - in the winter because of work, in the summer because of heat ;) it's fortunate that May is winter though - that definitely makes the long ride easier.

Comment: Why start slow/short? Bicycling is one of the few sports where you can really do tens of hours per week without significant risk of injury. Just make sure your bike fit is good and you don’t overtrain (usually not an issue for people who work full-time). Since the goal is long-distance riding there is really no way around relatively long (2h – 5h) training sessions at relatively low intensity.

Comment: Over training is entirely possible. You may not suffer 'injury' as most people define it, but you can certainly suffer excessively long recovery times, a very sore butt with saddle sores and the demoralizing effect of always being sore and tired and not being able to sit down. Better to start slow and loose a week or two building up than start fast and loose months because you loose motivation.

Comment: As an addition to the above comments, on the day of the event you will be focussed and will be able to push yourself further than in training - which means even if you haven't hit 280km in training, if you are close you will be able to push yourself that bit extra. In other words don't panic if you aren't hitting the targets and as mattnz says make sure you don't over-train and set yourself back.

Comment: @WyD1234 while it's not technically an event (it's going to be a solo ride), I know that I don't need to reach 280 km beforehand to ride 280 km on the day - for months before the 259 km ride I mentioned in the OP I didn't exceed 150 km in single rides, yet I managed. Thanks for your input though, and yours as well Michael

Comment: Also keep in mind that distance alone is just a factor. Elevation is another very important one, specially on a long ride. If it is a route you plan yourself, keep the steeper bites away from the finish. Then during training do not avoid the climbing to put more km in the pocket, but build up to that elevation too, 3.000 meters up is no joke, even distributed on 280 km.

Comment: @gaurwraith yeah, I'm aware of that as well, the elevation gain is what scares me more than the distance! That 259 km ride had about a thousand meters of climbing. The thing is, it's kinda hard to figure out a route that starts and ends near Sydney that wouldn't have some hills along the way, and over a long distance it racks up quickly. Even if I followed the river, i.e. stayed at a similar elevation most of the time, I'm getting about a hundred meters up every 25 km - and the river is nowhere near long enough to do this ride along it. I have a lot of time to figure out the exact route though

Comment: A well-defined solo ride can still feel like an event.  Maybe you don't get the full benefit that comes from a ride with other riders, but you certainly get some.